JQL in a filter is working sometimes, and sometimes not
In our Jira boards, we want to be able to filter FE and BE tickets by using the Quick filters. The tickets have a prefix of: "FE: (title)" or "BE: (title)".
My 2 queries are:
summary ~ FE
and
summary ~ BE
Strangely enough, the FE one works, while the BE one - no (showing 0 results). It won't work with a B only either, and it shows only 2 out of many tickets if I use the B* in the query.
What could be the problem?!

This one seems like being a very old issue:
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRACLOUD-44490
And in 2023, there has been a workaround proposed:
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Quick-filter-for-searching-BE-in-summary-not-working/qaq-p/2300075

After opening a ticket to Jira support, here's what they suggested and it did work out:
summary ~ "\"BE:\""

